# How to append to a Xml file for each operation?

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing a tool to reads a XMl(input) which contains paths to some folders and files and generate a XML(output) based on the information of all files mentioned in the path. I tried the  a code which reads the input xml file where i have give path to a certain folder within a certain tag. The tool works perfectly if i have mentioned only one path in the input xml. But on adding another path the previous the previous contents written to the XML(output) generated are overwritten.I have given the code below for the button event which generates the output XML on click and method that writes details to the XML. I an not sure how to append or where to append in the method that i write details to xml. Please help me out.

```
public bool GenerateReportFile(InputFile inputFile, string xmlfile)\\button clicked to perform operation
{
    //try
    //{
    // 
    foreach (var folder in inputFile.FolderList)
    {
        List<string> foldersList = GetSubFolders(folder);
        foldersList.Add(folder);

        UpdateFileInfomation(foldersList);

        SetVariable(folder);

        Serialize(xmlfile, typeof(DeploymentInfo), filesInformation);
    }

private static void Serialize(string xmlFilePath, Type type, object obj)\\method that writes contents to xml
{
    if (obj == null)
        return;

    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlFilePath)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlFilePath));

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath);\\this line creates a new XML file every time. this is where i need to handle things to avoid overwriting for every path mentioned in my input xml but i am unable to
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the `xmlfile`?

Comment: You mean the for input file or output file?

Comment: both,of course,more information is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to serialize objects of the same type at a single location you can add them to a list and serialize it instead.
Here is a tutorial: 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list

Edit:
This only works for Binary Serialization, not XML

You would need to rework your functions a bit:
Your GenerateReportFile should generate the list of objects and pass it to your Serialize

Comment: Accept the answer if it was the appropriate solution to your issue please :)